# Why the input is wrong in the program

Tags: java, swing

This is my program:

sub class:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class abc extends JPanel {

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        super.paintComponent(g);

        this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        int a, b;
        System.out.print("input a: ");
        a = input.nextInt();
        a = b;
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillOval(150, 40, a, b);
    }
}
```

main class:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class abcd {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Draw");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        abc panel = new abc();
        panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setSize(400, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Output always repeat; I have to input 3-4 times. 
I make this with sub class and main class.
Please help with this problem, and explain why it repeats?

Comment: Looping should hep you

Comment: Why are mixing a GUI with a CLI?  Input into your program should be coming from graphic input controls, like a `JTextField`. The reason it's repeating probably has something to do with the fact that you do not control the repaint process.  A repaint may occur at any time for any number of reasons...I suggest you make the time to have a read through [Creating a UI with Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)

Comment: 1) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow. 2) Don't set the size of top level containers.  Instead layout the content & call `pack()`. 3) Please add an upper case letter at the start of sentences.  Also use a capital for the word I, and abbreviations and acronyms like JEE or WAR.  This makes it easier for people to understand and help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed few things in your code that might be causing the problem :

```
public class abc extends JPanel{
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
super.paintComponent(g);

this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
int a,b;
System.out.print("input a: ");
a=input.nextInt();
```

a=b;`shouldn't this be b=a , maybe you did it by mistake?`

```
g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
g.fillOval(150,40,a,b);

}
```

Secondly, why are you painting the panel twice, first in the `abcd` class and also in `abc` class?

Comment: never use Scanner inside paintComponent, never to create anything  inside paintComponent